# What's the best way to implement below layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Now I have three ways to implement the layout:

**First:**

- UIScrollView

  - UICollectionView
  - UICollectionView
  - ...

**Second:**

- UICollectionView

  - UIScrollView
  - UIScrollView
  - ...

**Third:**

- UITableView

  - UICollectionView
  - UICollectionView
  - ...

Are there any other better ways?

[image: layout]

Comment: Finally, I use UITableView/UICollectionView to implement this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have different approach to integrate this type of UI Integration

I Use custom open source library use which is listed below.

- `UITableview`

  - `UITableViewHeader`

    - `UIView` Add into header
    - `UIScrollView` For Displaying Image
    - `UIView` For Blow Buttons
  - Adding Custom library Cell into the Horizontal and Vertical

Here is the List of the custom library that help lot

- [horizontalTableViewExample](https://github.com/diegoreymendez/horizontalTableViewExample)
- [EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView)
- Ray wenderlich step by step tutorial [part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) - [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

And if you want to use `UICollectionView` inside you can use `UITableView` for that refer below Tutorial.

- [Scrolling Filmstrip](http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/04/26/creating_scrolling_filmstrip_within_uitableview/)

May This help lot and solve your problem.